# Is Horner Algorithm works or suitable for polynomial with complex coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, algorithms, factoring

I have checked Algorithm of [Horner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner's_method) for  polynomial  factorization with

complex coeffecients ,I got it works but i can't show it works in general

for any polynomial with complex coeffeciant .

**My question here is**:How do I show it works or suitable for polynomial with complex coeffecients if it is ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What exactly is the point where you are stuck in proving it works? (I only glanced at it, but it looks like all that is used is distributivity of multiplication).

Comment: for example :if i want to factorise this polynomial such as defined as :p(x)=(2+3i)x^3+ix²+5x+2  at x=1+i , I ask if i can show that Algorithm of Horner valide and works for complex coeffecients in General .(I seek for a proof show that is works also for polynomial with complex  coeffecients)

Comment: This is not what I asked... you "seek a proof," and state "can't show it works in general." **Where** are you stuck in trying to showing it?  What doesn't go through in your proof attempt?